# Errai 4.0.0.Beta1 and UiBinder

Tags: gwt, uibinder, errai

errai-uibinder is no more available for errai 4.0 (4.0.0.Beta1) but using uibinder without the specific treatment seems to be the cause of some runtime problems at startup in my application. 
Has anyone successfully used UiBinder views with Errai 4.0 ?

Thanks,
  S.

Comment: Hi Sam, I you will include error trace and more details on the problem it will be more helpful others to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, Errai 4.0 will no longer support UiBinder. That's because generators will not be part of GWT 3.0. And because as long as no one will rewrite the Uibinder generators and replace them with APT, it will not work.

Take a look at the blog:

http://errai-blog.blogspot.de/2016/04/errai-400beta1-released.html

Errai offers an alternative way to create UIs.